# Testing that a plugin function is called in jenkins shared library

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, testing, groovy, continuous-integration

I'm trying to write a unit test for a util function in a Jenkins shared library. The util function, calls the `Office365Connector` plugin in Jenkins.

My util function looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import pe.ui.BuildNotificationSettings
import pe.ui.BuildStates

def call(BuildNotificationSettings options, BuildStates status) {

    options.teamsChannelWebhookUrlList.each {
        office365ConnectorSend (
            status: status.toString(),
            webhookUrl: "$it",
            color: BuildStates.valueOf(status.toString()).color,
            message: "Build ${status.toString()}: ${JOB_NAME} - ${BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME}<br>Pipeline duration: ${currentBuild.durationString}"
        )
    }

}
```

The use case that I'm trying to test is that the `office365ConnectorSend` function is called.

I've tried the following approach:

```
import com.homeaway.devtools.jenkins.testing.JenkinsPipelineSpecification
import pe.ui.BuildNotificationSettings
import pe.ui.BuildStates

public class _sendTeamsMessageSpec extends JenkinsPipelineSpecification {

    def _sendTeamsMessage = null

    def setup() {
        _sendTeamsMessage = loadPipelineScriptForTest("vars/_sendTeamsMessage.groovy")
        def office365ConnectorSend = Mock(office365ConnectorSend)
    }

    def "returns without sending no build notification settings are passed" () {
        given:
            def options = new BuildNotificationSettings(
                shouldSendNotification: null,
                teamsChannelWebhookUrlList: null
            )
        when:
            def result = _sendTeamsMessage(options, null)
        then:
            0 * explicitlyMockPipelineVariable("office365ConnectorSend")(_)
    }
}
```

running this on Jenkins gives me a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
There is no pipeline variable mock for [office365ConnectorSend].`, what am I doing wrong in this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following [this](https://github.com/homeaway/jenkins-spock/issues/38) thread, I ended up calling the `explicitlyMockPipelineStep` function on the `office365ConnectorSend` plugin function.
This made the function visible in the tests and I was able to resume testing.